# Counting enrollments by duration (<=4 years and >4 years) from yearly data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, I have these numbers of `new` people who have enrolled in our program each year (`10, 0, 0, 480, 0, 1800, 0, 10720, 0, 14, 0, 24, 0`). This data is recorded on `row 26` across `columns D to P`. That's 13 years in total. During that period, the number of enrolled people grew from `0` to `13,048`.

In `row 27`, for each year, I want to know the number of people who have been in the program for 4 years or less.

In `row 28`, I want to know the number of people who have been in the program for more than 4 years.

Answer (score 0):

Row 27. If cells `A26:C26` are empty or at least do not contain numbers nor errors you can use in `D27`:

```
=SUM(A$26:D$26)
```

and copy along the row. If cells `A26:C26` contain numbers you can use instead:

```
=SUM(A$26:D$26 $D:$P)
```

as shown in row 30 below.
Row 28. Starting from column H:

```
=SUM($D$26:D$26)
```

and copy along the row.
[image: Sums]

Comment: This wouldn't be generalizable. I wanted one formula to use in all cells on the row 27 and same formula in the row 28.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution that works. It turns out ChatGPT isn't completely useless after all.

Here we go:

`=if(count($D$26:D26)<=$AD$44, sum($D$26:D26), sum(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(27, COLUMN(D26) - ($AD$44-1))):D26))`

Type this in cell `D27` and drag the formula all the way.

In this formula, `$AD$44` is the address of the cell that contains the number `4`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).